# Page width bug because of Addthis script

Tags: html, css, addthis

Pages that have the AddThis code are very wide because of the AddThis code. As a result, a horizontal scroll bar appears.

Removing the code, or changing the page direction to LTR fixes everything and the page width is back to normal.

Like mentioned, the problem happens because I'm using RTL direction (html dir="rtl") and when I tried to put the Addthis code into a div which has direction LTR, it didn't help.

How can I get rid of the horizontal scroll bar and yet use a RTL direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and i found the fix in your question!!!

the RTL LTR is the point and what idid was to make CSS style for the inner div insted for the body.

```
    <body>
        <div class="wrraper">
       -- the cod for the addthis some where in the page... --
        </div>
    </body>
```

when in the css the .wrraper is position LTR insted of RTL
the  exem: 
  http://www.visualtext.co.il

Answer (score 3):

There are some spans in `AddThis` html which are automatically added to page. some of those spans use "`.at_a11y`" css-class in which there are a `left` attribute that is the main reason of horizontal scroll.

```
.at_a11y {
position: absolute!important;
left: -10000px!important;
top: auto!important;
width: 1px!important;
height: 1px!important;
overflow: hidden!important;
}
```

**Solution:** You can define your own '`.at_a11y`' css class in your own css files and override the `left` attribute to a normal value. This will cause the above css attribute to be useless and then horizental scroll will disappear!

```
.at_a11y
{
    left: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put `html{
overflow-x:hidden;
}` will solve this problem